# Using data-attributes inside fancyBox options

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Have searched for a solution to this but am coming up blank. I'm trying to set a data attribute and access it within the fancyBox options.

My anchor links looks like this:

```
<a class="expand" rel="gallery" href="/assets/images/larger-image.png" data-source="Some string" data-id="Some number">
    <img src="blah.jpg" />
</a>
```

And my JS:

```
$(".expand").fancybox({
    'padding' : 0,
    'tpl' : {
        image : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />'
    }
});
```

What I'd like to be able to do is access those data-attributes inside the `tpl` option.

```
$(".expand").fancybox({
    'padding' : 0,
    'tpl' : {
        image : '<h2>' + $(this.element).data('source') + '</h2><img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" /><h3>' + $(this.element).data('id') + '</h3>'
    }
});
```

I can't access `this.element` in that context; is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `tpl` is used to format specific elements of the fancybox structure so this

```
'tpl' : {
        image : '<h2>' + $(this.element).data('source') + '</h2><img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" /><h3>' + $(this.element).data('id') + '</h3>'
    }
```

it's a bit odd since you are adding elements that are not part of the `image` template (normally you would use it to add *classes* or other *attributes*, etc.)

Anyways, if this is what you want, you first need to use a fancybox callback to have access to the `data` attributes ( `$(this.element)` can only be accessed inside a callback ).

Then you may need to use the `jQuery.extend()` method to modify the fancybox *template* on the fly (from within the `afterLoad` callback) like :

```
$(".expand").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function () {
        $.extend(this, {
            tpl: {
                image: '<h2>' + $(this.element).data('source') + '</h2><img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" /><h3>' + $(this.element).data('id') + '</h3>'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w1y5b3kh/)**

Comment: Cheers mate – that works perfectly (and agree there's probably a better approach for this type of functionality).

Comment: @AndyMcCray : here is a similar question/answer using that possible different approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/25415852/1055987

Comment: Fantastic – am using that approach now.