# fancybox gallery with custom append elements

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

before opening fancybox gallery i append elements into fancybox inner window but size dosent change and appende't element are overflowed.. , how to resize'it ?

my problem - http://prntscr.com/4esnpq

html

```
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="demo/img1.jpg" >
        <b>title1</b>
        <em>text1</em>
        img1
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="demo/img2.jpg" >
        <b>title2</b>
        <em>text2</em>
        img2
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="demo/img3.jpg" >
         <b>title3</b>
        <em>text3</em>
        img3
    </a>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="demo/img4.jpg" >
        <b>title4</b>
        <em>text4</em>
        img4
    </a>
```

javascript

```
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({

            padding: 35,
            titleShow: false,

            beforeShow:function() {

                var title = $(this.element).find('b').text();
                var text = $(this.element).find('em').text();

                $('.fancybox-inner').prepend('<b>'+ title +'</b>');
                $('.fancybox-inner').append('<em>'+ text +'</em>');

                $.fancybox.update();

            }

        });
```

any solution ? fancybox version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found good solution editing main fancybox library.

1. In `defaults` define new `attach_size: 0`
2. In function `_setDimension` find `F.inner.width(width - padding2).height(height - padding2);` and replace it with `F.inner.width(width - padding2).height(height - padding2 + current.attach_size);`
3. Change fancybox element handle to

   ```
               $(".fancybox").fancybox({

               padding: 35,
               titleShow: false,

               beforeShow:function() {

                   var title = $(this.element).find('b').text();
                   var text = $(this.element).find('em').text();

                   $('.fancybox-inner').prepend('<b>'+ title +'</b>');
                   $('.fancybox-inner').append('<em>'+ text +'</em>');

                   var sum_size = $('.fancybox-inner b').height() + $('.fancybox-inner em').height();

                   this.attach_size += sum_size;

               }

           });
   ```

works good for me ;)

Comment: Normally it's not a good idea to mess with original plugin files since the day you (or another developer) update the plugin , your functionality will break. It's better to use a separated custom script for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to do that with images because the fancybox size is calculated on the fly by the script based on the image size, not the `.fancybox-inner` size.

You may need to handle the content as `html`, something like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    type: "html",
    beforeShow: function () {
        var title = $(this.element).find('b').text();
        var text = $(this.element).find('em').text();
        $('.fancybox-inner').html('<img style="max-width:300px" src="' + this.href + '" alt="" />');
        $('.fancybox-inner').prepend('<b>' + title + '</b>');
        $('.fancybox-inner').append('<em>' + text + '</em>');
        $.fancybox.update();
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/skpL5z53/)**

Comment: Is it possible to do same trick on fancybox-3 ? I have tried and wild error appeared `Uncaught TypeError: t.fancybox.update is not a function`